# Did the @POTUS Twitter account use a picture from Obama's inauguration for its cover image?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, barack-obama

There's an image going around Facebook claiming that the @POTUS Twitter account is using an image from President Obama's inauguration.

[image: Screenshot of @POTUS' Twitter page combined with another image with the caption: 'Hmm, where have we seen Trump’s new Twitter background? Oh right, it’s from Obama’s inauguration.']

Is this true? Where is the original image from?

Comment: *No one is claiming that either Trump or his staff used the wrong image*. Please be careful when writing questions to be *neutral*. Now that I edited the question without indicating possible guilt, the question does not seem very controversial anymore.

Comment: So, is it plausible to claim that the image was "accidentally" used, because it was already somehow "sitting around" the POTUS Twitter account, or would it require some degree of intent?

Comment: @DanielRHicks seeing as the image was probably put up there in preparation of the inauguration, actual images of Trump's inauguration wouldn't have been available yet. In which case it's likely to be changed again soon (if it hasn't already).

Comment: The handle was passed from the Obama administration to the Trump administration; it's possible that the background is simply an artifact from the previous owner.

Comment: @8protons - That was my question -- how plausible is it that it was an "artifact" that was unknowingly employed?

Answer (score 185, accepted):

It is a [photo from Getty Images](http://www.gettyimages.com/license/157419604) covering Obama's 2009 inauguration.

[image]

> Barack Obama's Presidential Inauguration at Capitol Building, Washington DC
>   Credit: [carterdayne](http://www.gettyimages.com.au/search/photographer?family=creative&photographer=carterdayne)
>   [...]
>   The inauguration of President Barack Obama, January 20th 2009. Unrecognizable crowds in the Washington Mall.

You can note that the weather in the picture is quite sunny but the weather during the 2017 inauguration was overcast.

Obama last used a background of the 50th anniversary march at Selma, captured by [archive.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20170120165855/https://twitter.com/POTUS) about a minute before the switch. The Obama inauguration photo is the first Trump background captured by [archive.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20170120170120/https://twitter.com/POTUS) (about a minute after the switch.) (The Selma photo is what Obama used when he started using the POTUS account in 2015, again as captured by [archive.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20150518164058/https:/twitter.com/POTUS).)